# Python 3 Tkinter custom font in Label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, font-family

I want make custom font in my label as @front-family in css ?

```
font = "C:/Users/Alex/Documents/myproject/Call of Ops Duty.otf"
mylabel = Label(main, text="This is a text", bg="black", fg="#fff", font=(font, 30))
```

and

```
mylabel = Label(main, text="This is a text", bg="black", fg="#fff", font=(Call of Ops Duty.otf, 30))
```

and

```
mylabel = Label(main, text="This is a text", bg="black", fg="#fff", font=("Call of Ops Duty", 30))
```

It does not work ;(

Comment: Have you installed this font in your computer?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use fonts these way. Tkinter can only use fonts installed on the system.

Answer (score 0):

The only fonts that you can use with Tkinter are the preset ones:

1. TkDefaultFont
   Default for items not otherwise specified.
2. TkTextFont
   Used for entry widgets, listboxes, etc.
3. TkFixedFont
   A standard fixed-width font.
4. TkMenuFont
   The font used for menu items.
5. TkHeadingFont
   Font for column headings in lists and tables.
6. TkCaptionFont
   A font for window and dialog caption bars.
7. TkSmallCaptionFont
   A smaller caption font for tool dialogs.
8. TkIconFont
   A font for icon captions.
9. TkTooltipFont
   A font for tooltips.

https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/fonts.html

This means that you can't import your own font onto your labels